# браузерное выделение текста

Tags: html, css

здравствуйте, есть кнопка  при нажатии которой происходит срабатывание функции, но часто бывает что нажимаешь двойным кликом, и из-за этого ссылка выделяется синим цветом, я посмотрел на других сайтах такого нет, как можно решить проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать свойство `user-select: none;`

Comment: спасибо помогло , но не совсем, теперь синее выделение текста вообще отсутствует, даже когда сам специально выделяешь